# After update Android Stuido 4.1 in Ubuntu 18.4 can't open facing this issue

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

**After update Android Stuido 4.1 in Ubuntu 18.4 can't open facing this issue**

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
    
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
        at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your android studio not opening properly after updated.
Just press CTR+H in File manager (show hidden files). now you can see the .local file.
now go to remove the google file from there. (Path -> local/share/google).

Answer (score 4):

please remove the file .local/share/google and Open android studio it will work.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! :D